# Send Mail System Net mail detected as virus by Avira

Tags: .net, email, basic, antivirus

I compile my program with inno setup.
Then uploaded the installer to my server, because another user can downloaded on their pc.

I'm trying to send a mail, by function, but the Avira antivirus detected my program as virus, i tried run my program without this function, and its not detected by antivirus. This just occur when download from my server http.

```
    Private Sub EnviarMail(mailto As String, respuesta As String, asunto As String)

    Try

        Dim Smtp_Server As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
        Dim e_mail As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
        Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        Smtp_Server.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(CredencialMail, CredencialPassword)
        Smtp_Server.Port = 587
        Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = False
        Smtp_Server.Host = "smtp.1und1.de"
        Smtp_Server.DeliveryFormat = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network

        e_mail = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
        e_mail.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(CredencialMail)
        e_mail.To.Add(mailto)
        e_mail.Subject = asunto
        e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
        e_mail.Body = respuesta

        Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)

        MsgBox("Mail Sent")

    Catch error_t As Exception

        MsgBox(error_t.ToString)

    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only difference between it working normally and being detected as a virus is that it's downloaded, then it is likely a certificate signing issue.  If this is something commercial that you intend to make available, you may want to get a code signing certificate.  Inno Setup handles that process nicely.

It's not cheap and it's not free, either, but without it your clients will get the "Unknown publisher" message whenever they attempt to run a downloaded program, at best, and sometimes, as I suspect is the case with you, a false virus detection.

Search your Inno Setup help for code signing for further information.